# Exception: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x010FF288 when using std::stoi

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that is supposed to encrypt numbers.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>

int intToBin(int num)
{
    std::string bin = "";
    while (num > 0)
    {
        bin += std::to_string(num % 2);
        num /= 2;
    }

    std::reverse(begin(bin), end(bin));
    int nBin = std::stoi(bin);
    return nBin;
}

int XOR(int b1, int b2)
{
    if (b1 == 1 && b2 == 1)
        return 0;
    else if (b1 == 0 && b2 == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int encrypt(int value, int key)
{
    std::string encrypted = "";

    value = intToBin(value);
    key = intToBin(key);

    std::string sValue = std::to_string(value);
    std::string sKey = std::to_string(key);
    
    int valueIteration = 0;
    while (valueIteration < sValue.size())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sKey.size(); i++)
        {
            encrypted += std::to_string(XOR(sKey[i], sValue[valueIteration]));
            valueIteration++;
        }
    }
    return std::stoi(encrypted);
}

int main()
{
    int code = encrypt(1500, 4);
    std::cout << code << std::endl;
}
```

But, I am getting an exception during runtime on line `int nBin = std::stoi(bin);`

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77704662 in learnc++.exe: 
Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x003BF9C0.
```

I wrote `intToBin` function first and it was running fine when I tested it. The problem started when I added `encrypt` function.

Also, I don't know why but I am getting a `signed/unsigned mismatch` warning on lines `while (valueIteration < sValue.size())` and `for (int i = 0; i < sKey.size(); i++)` if it is somehow related.

Comment: FWIW, if you want to convert an integer into a bit string, use `std::bitset`.

Comment: If `sKey.size()` is greater than `sValue.size()`, what happens to `sValue[valueIteration]`?

Comment: `valueIteration` and `i` are declared as (signed) `int`. The `size()` function returns an unsigned value.

Comment: @NathanOliver It would stop in the first iteration? I just tried it and got a subscript error..oof

Comment: It shouldn't.  Your loop is `for (int i = 0; i < sKey.size(); i++)` no where do you stop that loop if `valueIteration` becomes `>= sValue.size()`

Comment: @jkb why does size return unsigned value when size can't be negative?

Comment: @NathanOliver Ahh, so I have to add `if (valueIteration < sValue.size()) break;` in the inner loop isn't it?

Comment: @hippozhipos "why does size return unsigned value when size can't be negative?" is a question that answers itself. `size` returns unsigned because the size can't be negative.

Comment: That or just use `for (int i = 0; i < sKey.size() && valueIteration < sValue.size(); i++)`.

Comment: @hippozhipos `size` returns an unsigned value a) *because* the size cannot be negative, and b) to allow a greater range of positive values for size.

Comment: It worked when I did `int code = encrypt(100, 4);` but not with `int code = encrypt(1500, 4);`